# Upload csv file in database - php

Tags: php, csv, file-upload, fgetcsv

This is my code. I get the error "Notice: Undefined offset: 9". If I have until the $item9 it works but i want actually to have until $item13.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if($_FILES['file']['name'])
    {
        $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        if($filename[1] == 'csv')
        {
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
            while($data = fgetcsv($handle))
            {
                $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]);
                $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]);
                $item3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[2]);
                $item4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[3]);
                $item5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[4]);
                $item6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[5]);
                $item7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[6]);
                $item8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[7]);
                $item9 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[8]);
                $item10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[9]);


                $query = "INSERT into tab1(country, jan, feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug) values('$item1','$item2','$item3','$item4','$item5','$item6','$item7','$item8','$item9','$item10')";
                mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            }
            fclose($handle);
```

Comment: No, my error is for undefined offset

Comment: And the third notice-type in that dupe q is.. ?

Comment: One of your rows doesn't have a 9th index. Do a `print_r($data)` inside your `while` and look at the output for each row (comment out your variable declarations/query)

Comment: I tried it but the error still the same

Comment: @PX. print r simply outputs data so you can see it on screen and debug - it's not a fix

Comment: i think its because of the empty columns. so i need to find a way to skip if the rows are empty or put 0 in value of the field

Answer (score 0):

You answer yourself in last comment. So do what you say - eg. replace each item row like this:

```
$item1 = array_key_exists(0, $data) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]) : '0';
```

Comment: i tried it and the error remains the same

Comment: Did you replace properly values from example? Read about array_key_exists function and shorthand if/else. Good luck :)